# importar modulos de forma asincrona

Tags: javascript

Necesito poder hacer la carga de módulos según vaya necesitando.  Ahora mismo, tengo un sistema en el que tengo que importar a la fuerza todos los módulos que tengo y después usarlos a medida que necesite, pero esto consume mucha memoria, es lento y se puede optimizar.

Lo que pretendo es que, si necesito dos módulos, SOLO cargue dichos módulos, no tenga que cargar tropecientos.

Ahora mismo tengo así la función que lo controla:

```
async function dynamicClass(json){//llamo a la funcion de forma asincrona y meto un json como parametro
    let listClass = [];

    for(const key in json){//en dicho json definire que tipo de etiquetas html quiero insertar en el DOM, las key en este caso

        if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(json, key)) {

            let requredClass = 'Module._' + json[key]['type'];/*para no tener que ir una por una, defino la variable
requiredClass con el tipo de etiqueta html que mando a traves del json
*/

            await import('../modules/'+ requredClass+ '.js').then((Module) => {//y aqui importar de forma asincrona
//los modulos que haya requerido de forma dinamica

                listClass[key] = (Function('return new Module.' + requredClass))(json[key]);
//parece que no se puede instanciar la variable dentro del return
            });
        }

    }
```

El caso es que nada de lo que he probado funciona, tanto mi compañero como yo hemos mirado medio internet estos días para solucionarlo, y hay algo que siempre falla.

---

**[EDIT]**

```
await import('../modules/'+ requredClass+ '.js').then(Module => {
                let dynamic = eval("new Module." + requredClass + "()" );
            });
```

Con esta forma de hacerlo, nos faltaría poner, de forma que no de error, `json[key]` dentro del parentesis vacío de `dynamic`. Algo así:

```
let dynamic = eval("new Module." + requredClass + "("+json[key]+")" );
```

Obviamente esto da error, y así con todas las pruebas que hemos hecho...

---

**[EDIT 2]**

```
let dynamic = eval('new Module.' + requredClass + '('+JSON.stringify(json[key])+')' );
```

Con esta variable, gracias al JSON.stringify de json[key] podemos ver etiquetas simples, como botones, divs, etc

El problema viene cuando el json, que es lo normal, tiene un contenido dentro, un div que contiene objetos simples, como botones, etc.

el json quedaría algo como esto:

```
let json = [{
            "type" : "div",
            "content" : [
                {
                    "type" : "button"
                }
            ]
        }]
```

Dicho button no se vería, se vería un DIV vacío

Comment: Existe una forma de importar modulos de forma d8nsmica , lo estoy buscando, no recuerdo donde lo vi

Comment: Si, yo también tengo ejemplos donde lo hacía con un switch, pero no les valía. Tiene que ser de una manera que a través del json, si mandamos crear un div, se importe el modulo de creación del div, y si mandamos un div, un button, a, p, textfield etc, se carguen TODOS ellos, pero ninguno más.
Igualmente lo hemos hecho, pero se hace por orden de carga, y eso al final no es bueno, porque nuestro orden se lo saltan a la torera

Comment: @AQMR https://javascript.info/modules-dynamic-imports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
listClass[key] = eval('new Module.' + requredClass + '(' +JSON.stringify(json[key])+')' );
```

Con esto se consiguió resolver el problema. Ahora, lo que hace toda la función es introducir en el DOM los elementos por orden de CARGA, no por el orden que nosotros le mandemos. Es decir, el elemento que MENOS pese, irá primero, independientemente de su orden deseado.

Pero bueno, la pregunta ya fue respondida al menos...